# How to get the .NET Type from Java.Lang.Class instance or JNI type?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android, java-native-interface

I'm using Xamarin.Android and I'm trying to extend the functionality of the default `FragmentFactory`.

```
public class ExtendedFragmentFactory : FragmentFactory
{
    public override Fragment Instantiate(ClassLoader classLoader, string className)
    {
        Class javaClass = Class.ForName(className, false, classLoader);
        var instance = javaClass.NewInstance();
    }
}
```

If I create a new instance using `NewInstance()`, then I am able to call `GetType()` on `instance` which does give me the .NET Type but how would I do this without unnecessarily creating an instance?

I'm trying to get the Dependency Container to create the `Fragment` so I am not able to use the default instantiation method that Android uses with `FragmentManager` or `FragmentFactory`. My `Fragment` classes will have dependencies injected into them via their constructor, in other words, I will not have a parameterless constructor which the default instantiation implementation expects.

Is there any way to get the .NET Type from Java.Lang.Class or the specified parameters in the `Instantiate` method?

Is there any way I can use the `className` parameter to work out what the .NET Type is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `TypeManager`, I managed to get the .NET managed Type from the `className` parameter.

```
Type type = JniEnvironment.Runtime.TypeManager.GetType(JniTypeSignature.Parse($"[L{className.Replace('.', '/')};"))!;
if (type.IsGenericType)
{
    type = type.GetGenericArguments().First();
}
```

The `className` value needed to be "converted" to a valid JNI signature which is relatively simple to do, it just requires a primitive understanding of JNI.

The value returned is of Type `Java.Interop.JavaObjectArray<T>` so a call to `GetGenericArguments()` will get you the correct .NET managed Type.

---

By using the `RegisterAttribute`, I was able to find a way to ensure `className` has the fully qualified name of the .NET Type.

```
[Register("Namespace.SomeFragment")
public class SomeFragment : Fragment
{
}
```

This is a somewhat tedious process especially if you have many `Fragment` classes (like me).

Answer (score 0):

`Java.Lang.Class` by default has the GetType() method:

```
Class javaClass = Class.ForName(className, false, classLoader);
var dotNetType = javaClass.GetType();
```

Comment: I don't want the .NET Type of `Java.Lang.Class`, I want the .NET Type that `javaClass` represents. Calling `GetType()` on `javaClass` is effectively the same as `typeof(Java.Lang.Class)` which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Aah, now your question makes more sense :P